# What is the supplement of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3618720/567282)
answer it is said the "supplement of $\mathrm{Nuc} (g)$", but it is not clear to me from the context what this means. And I don't find the definition anywhere on the internet.

Thanks.

p.s: Math StackExchange doesn't allow me to contact Ewan Delanoy or comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A supplement of a subspace $V$ of a vector space $E$ is a subspace $W$ of $E$ such that $$E = V \oplus W$$

That means that for all $x \in E$, there exists a unique pair $(v,w) \in V \times W$ such that $x=v+w$.

(Actually, I am not sure that the term "supplement" is correct in English... maybe there is another term ; but we say "supplémentaire" in French, which is what Ewan Delanoy means)

Comment: May I ask what the difference between a direct complement and a supplement is?

Comment: Well, I guess this is the same thing ! In French, we avoid to use the word "complémentaire", which would rather design $E \setminus V$ (which of course is not a subspace), so we say "supplémentaire" : but maybe the correct translation in English is "direct complement".